# Java server/client chatting program

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

So i am trying to create a simple java chat program that asks the user for a unique username to be stored on the server and then that username is to be used by other clients to send messages.Now the usernames are stored correctly and the messages are sent to the server correctly.However,I can't find a way to send the messages from the server to a different client. Here is the code:
The format for a client to send a message to another client is username  >> message

Server files :

```
import java.util.List;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream; 
    public class server {
        //List of client names and client handlers (capital)
        private static List<String> clientNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        private static List<Capital> clients = new ArrayList<Capital>();
        public static boolean addName(String name) {
            if(clientNames.contains(name))
                return false;
            else
              clientNames.add(name);
            return true;

        }
        public static void addClient (Capital c) {
            clients.add(c);
        }
        public static String getMembers(){
         return clientNames.toString();
        }
        //Send a message to another client
        public static void directSend(String sender,String Receiver,String Message) 
            {
            Stream <Capital> clientStream = clients.stream();
            clientStream.forEach( client -> { 
                    if(client.getName().equals(Receiver)) {
                        Socket socket = client.getSocket();
                        System.out.println(client.getName());
                         OutputStream os;
                        try {
                            os = socket.getOutputStream();
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os, true);
                            out.println("From "+ sender+":"+ Message);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

            });
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("The server is running.");
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
            int clientNumber = 0;
            try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(6789)) {
            while (true) {
            pool.execute(new Capital(listener.accept(),
            clientNumber++));
            }
      }
     }
    }
```

Client handler (called Capital):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public  class Capital implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;
    private String clientName;
    //constants to define message types
    private static final int JOIN = 1;
    private static final int SEND = 2;
    private static final int ACCEPTED = 3;
    private static final int REJECTED = 4;
    private static final int MEMBERS = 5;
    public Capital(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        System.out.println("New client #" + clientNumber + "connected at " + socket);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.clientName;
    }
    public Socket getSocket() {
        return this.socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byte messageType = in.readByte();
        BufferedReader inContent = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String messageContent = inContent.readLine();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        //handle each message type accordingly
        switch(messageType) {
        case JOIN:if(server.addName(messageContent)) {
                  out.write(ACCEPTED);
                  out.println("Welcome to the server "+messageContent);
                  this.clientName = messageContent;
                  server.addClient(this);
                }
                else {
                  out.write(REJECTED);
                  out.println("This name is already taken try again");  
                }
                break;
        case SEND: out.write(ACCEPTED);
                    String[] contentSplit = messageContent.split(" ");
                    String sender = contentSplit[0];
                    String Receiver = contentSplit[1];
                    String message = messageContent.substring(
                                    messageContent.indexOf("#")+1);
                    server.directSend(sender, Receiver, message);
                    out.println("Message Sent");
                   break;
        case MEMBERS:out.write(ACCEPTED);
                     out.println(server.getMembers());
                     break;

        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error handling client #" + clientNumber);
         e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Client files :

```
import java.io.*;
public class MainClient {
    private static boolean acceptFlag = true;
    private static String acceptedName;

    public static void setFlag(boolean result) {
        acceptFlag = result;
    }
    public static void setName(String name) {
        acceptedName = name;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while(acceptFlag) {
        System.out.print("Please Enter your name: ");
        BufferedReader reader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputName = reader.readLine();
        Client client = new Client(""+inputName);
        client.join();
        }
        Client client = new Client(""+acceptedName);
        System.out.println("Type Members any time to get "
                + "a list of available members");
        client.run();




    }
}
```

Client Instance

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class Client {
          String sentence;
          String modifiedSentence;
          String name;
          //constants to define message types
          private static final int JOIN = 1;
          private static final int SEND = 2;
          private static final int ACCEPTED = 3;
          private static final int MEMBERS = 5;
          public Client(String name) {
              this.name = name;
          }
          public void join() throws IOException {
            this.sendMessage(this.name,JOIN,null,null);

          }
          public void sendMessage(String message,int type,String sender,String receiver) 
          throws IOException {
              Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",6789);
              DataOutputStream outToServer = 
                      new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
              InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader inFromServer =
                      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                      outToServer.writeByte(type);
                      if(sender!=null) {
                          outToServer.writeBytes(sender+" "+receiver+"#");
                      }
                      outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');
                      try {
                      if(inputStream.read()==ACCEPTED) {
                          MainClient.setFlag(false);
                          MainClient.setName(this.name);
                      }
                      else {
                          MainClient.setFlag(true);
                      }
                      modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                      System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);}
                      catch(Exception e) {
                          System.out.println("Error sending the message,Try again");
                      }
                      finally {
                          clientSocket.close(); 
                      }

          }               
          public void run() throws Exception {
          boolean socketFlag = true;
          while(socketFlag) {
          System.out.print("Message:");
          BufferedReader inFromUser = 
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          String inputMessage = inFromUser.readLine();
          switch(inputMessage) {
            case "Bye" : socketFlag=false;break;
            case "Members" : this.sendMessage("",MEMBERS,null,null);break;
            default: String receiver = inputMessage.split(">>")[0];
                     String message = inputMessage.substring(inputMessage.indexOf('>')+2);
                this.sendMessage(message,SEND,this.name,receiver);
                break;  
          }


            }

          }

      }
```